# How to add a program that is not installed via APT/dpkg to launcher?

Tags: launcher, 14.04, adt

I installed Android Development Tools (you just download it and run the executable file inside a folder). I want to pin the ADT to the launcher, but I don't know how to do that. I tried to drag the executable file, but it didn't work. I also tried to click "Lock to the launcher"(on the right click when it's running), but it also didn't work. Any ideas?

Edit1: If I create shortcut like in the [article you claim answers my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand). Can I install normal eclipse and set it in a way it's the same like ADT downloaded from android.com? I tried that as well, but some features are missing.

Edit2: When I try to run it, what I get is an error message saying `There was an error launching the application`

Edit3: This is what I typed

```
Desktop Entry]
Name=Eclipse
Type=Application Exec='/home/dusan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/eclipse/eclipse'
Terminal=false
Icon='/home/dusan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/eclipse/icon.xpm'
Comment=Eclipse
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=Eclipse.desktop
```

Edit4: Eclipse launched successfuly.

Edit5: I also tried without apostrophes, but I get the same error message as in Edit2.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand - you need to create a `.desktop` file for it.

Comment: Takkat, please remove the duplicate tag, because this IS NOT a duplicate!

Comment: What's a typo?.

Comment: The message in your screenshot from your 2nd edit indicates an error in the .desktop file. Spot the error, remove it, and you will be able to run Eclipse from a .dektop file (which then can be dragged onto the laucher).

Comment: I cannot find the error. I did everything as described. I showed the code of .desktop, so please take a look at it and see if you can find an error.

Comment: Your terminal screenshot shows at least two errors... 1. line missing `[`, 3. line missing `new line` after "Application". Double check the paths are correct. Save the .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications` and make it permission "executable".

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You should create a Desktop Entry first:
Go in terminal and write:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/adt.desktop
```

and write inside of editor:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ADT
Type=Application
Exec=/home/dusan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/eclipse/eclipse 
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/dusan/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/eclipse/eclipse.xpm
Comment=Any comment
NoDisplay=false
Categories=Development;IDE
Name[en]=adt.desktop
```

Replace `Icon` and `Exec` with the path to Eclipse. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> followed by <kbd>Y</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you have desktop entry in Dashboard.
Drag it to your launcher. May need to logout.

Comment: It's not working. Eclipse won't start.

Comment: be sure you put the paths to your eclipse executable correctly.

Comment: I did. The same thing happens like I ran eclipse and clicked "Lock to Launcher".

Comment: put a break behind Type=Application; Exec should be in newline

Comment: Worked for me!!

Comment: Does not work in Ubuntu 16.04