# How do I add an icon to an executable file

Tags: icons, executable

I have several utility programs that I can run only by clicking on their "generic" executable file. How can I assign an icon to each of them for it to show in the Launcher? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

- Create a "*Application_name*.desktop" file using gedit or any other text editor with contents
  [Desktop Entry]
  Name=*Application name*
  Exec=*path-to-executable*
  Icon=*path-to-icon*
  Terminal=false
  Type=Application
- put it in **~/.local/share/applications**
- For complete documentation checkout https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles

Comment: or /usr/share/applications

Comment: In my case (Ubuntu 20.04), I had to Suspend and then LogIn for changes to take effect. You can Restart too.

Answer (score 2):

Follow steps here 
Your question is disscused in this thread. Check the answer !
https://askubuntu.com/a/450847