# How to add program to launcher in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher

The proposed approaches: 
Locking the opened program in the launcher via right click - does not have any effect.

Right clicking unused space in the panel (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToAddaLauncher) - nothing happens

Creating a desktop file ([How to add a program that is not installed via APT/dpkg to launcher?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450843/how-to-add-a-program-that-is-not-installed-via-apt-dpkg-to-launcher)) - does not have any effect either, even after restarting

---

The respective program is PHP Storm and I would prefer to keep Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: At least in Ubuntu 17.04, right-klick on the program an "Keep in launcher" works fine. Maybe an dist upgrade (https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html) could solve this problem.

Comment: This no longer works in 18.04.  Do you know how to submit this as an ubuntu bug/issue?